# The second verb of subject should be express according to number or not?

Tags: verbs, grammatical-number, word-usage

> He is a man who has a bad heart.

or

> He is a man who have a bad heart.

Which one is correct?

I tried to search `"He is a man who have"` and `"He is a man who has"` on Google but I got quite the same number of matched result, So, I'm not sure which one should be correct.

Comment: Suggest migration to [ELL.se].

Comment: You have to be *very* careful with Google. I've been burned many a time. Click on page 5 and you'll find the vertiginous number of 37 million hits drops dramatically to 43 hits for ["He is a man who have"](https://www.google.it/search?q=He+is+a+man+who+have&oq=He+is+a+man+who+have&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22He+is+a+man+who+have%22&start=40)

Comment: Whereas ["he is a man who has"](https://www.google.it/search?q=He+is+a+man+who+have&oq=He+is+a+man+who+have&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22He+is+a+man+who+has%22&start=50) gets 41 million hits even on page 5

Answer (score 1):

Everywhere except on Google

**He is a man who has...** is all singular.

**They are men who have** (bad hearts). -is all plural.

The interesting question is how google rates both your versions the same.

Comment: See my comment above :) [37 million hits](https://www.google.it/search?q=He+is+a+man+who+have&oq=He+is+a+man+who+have&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22He+is+a+man+who+have%22) for "He is a man who have", including speech marks. I will NEVER understand Google. Ever.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just say he has a bad heart. But generally I would only say that if he has a heart condition, it's rather old fashioned to say it to describe someone as wicked. It would be better to say he has bad intentions, or is unethical or immoral.

Comment: That doesn't answer may question my point is about grammar.

Comment: He is a man who has a bad heart, is the correct one, but while he can be a he and not a man, I think adding man in is a little lacking in style. But if you just want to know which is correct it is "He is a man who has a bad heart".